# Add something after 2 elements using $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, insertafter

I would like to add something after the 2nd or 3d element of `$(this)`. This is actually always a form, just to let you know. After this form there are some other elements and at the the end there is another form, where you can go back.

After this form i would like to add a message, if a comment has been created, but how can i do something like:

```
$(this).after.after("<p class='success'>The comment has been edited!</p>");
```

or something like where i can also use the name of the class the form has? Actually the form to go back has the name back.

I actually need to use `$(this)` because else the message is added for each comment.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for the same?

Comment: although not really an answer, you'd be better off having `<p class='success'>` in the dom and accessing that directly. having javascript (or css for that matter) dependent on a dom structure like that leads to issues further down the line

Comment: @Pratik Why? i guess it's clear enough?

Comment: @atmd the problem is that i probably don't need the class, else i would probably add it to the html. It just needs to be added for a comment that is edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To target the next element if it is a form use `.next('form')`

```
$(this).next('form').after("<p class='success'>The comment has been edited!</p>");
```

To target something after two or three elements you can use the current index and add to it, and then eq to get that sibling

```
$(this).siblings().eq($(this).index() + 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I don't found anything using a search, at least not using $(this) and i didn't get it work using $(this).

Comment: `.next('form')` does not get the *"next form"*, but the next *element* (and only if it's a form)

Comment: Indeed, and that would be the next form in this case

Comment: I think it will be `next().next()` (if the form is 2nd element after *this*), and `next().next().next()` (if the form is 3nd element after *this*)  http://jsfiddle.net/4xcgpr4n/ Or do I fiddle it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To insert after the next **closest** form use `.nextAll('form')[0]`

```
$("<p class='success'>The comment has been edited!</p>")
.insertAfter($(this).nextAll('form')[0]);
```

This will insert the HTML after the first occurrence of the form (after `$(this)`)